# Compare Datetime.now to date on SQL table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqlcommand

I'm trying to write code on c# that will compare between date that i have on SQL table (table:items, column "endTime") against datetime.now and by the result - display image.

example:

if the time on the column table is before the time now.. so display on the aspx image1, else display image2.

i've tried to do that by sql command:

```
    private DateTime endTime(out int lastDate)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=******;User ID=*****;Integrated Security=False;");
    string commandtext = "SELECT TOP(1) endTime FROM items";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, connection);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandtext, connection);
    lastDate = (int)command2.ExecuteScalar(); 
    connection.Close();
    return ...
}
```

but i have problem with the return, and with the execution of the method... :

```
            int d; 
        Console.WriteLine(endTime(out d));
        if (d < DateTime.Now)
        {
            image1.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            image2.Visible = true;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(d);
```

but i got error, but i believe it's come from the return.

Comment: I'm sorry, but `I got error` is not very descriptive of the problem you are having.

Comment: "i got error" is about as vague as you can get, with the added benefit of being terrible English. What error/what line/etc.

Comment: This code isn't complete and makes no sense...

Comment: the problem is on the vwd on the line with: if(d< DateTime.Now) ... the error: operator < cannot..... of type int and ....System.datetime.  i have tried to change int to datetime but i dont know what to do with the return in this case.

Comment: @Mannimarco  thank you, but not everyone have great english like yours... i'm trying to write as best as i can. who can try to help i'll be appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if (d < DateTime.Now)` use this: `if (d < DateTime.Now.Date)`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be casting out a DateTime from your query and not an int? Also, the stack trace/debugger should give you the line number of the exception. Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: the problem is on the vwd on the line with: if(d< DateTime.Now) ... the error: operator < cannot..... of type int and ....System.datetime.  i have tried to change int to datetime but i dont know what to do with the return in this case.

Comment: Just make your signature  private DateTime `endTime(out DateTime lastDate)` and change the other code to `lastDate = (DateTime)command2.ExecuteScalar();`    Also, why do you have the command running twice?

Comment: be careful when casting DateTime, take a look at the SqlDateTime class

Comment: thanks. My mistake because i copied it from other code that work for other thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is returned by your sql query (I believe ticks)?
2. How do you convert `int` into `DateTime`, show a code please
3. Enclose SqlConnection in `using()` block as shown below:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest letting the database do the date comparison right in the sql.

SYSDATE can be compared to EndTime right in the query, and you can either not bring back rows that dont match (which allows you to process every row in the result set equally) or you check a simple value in the return set to see if the time is in the right period.

Comment: i have other question that maybe will give me the solution. how can i do : if (lable.text = "end")  ... image1.visble;  ? how can i check on if somthing that wrote on lable  ?